# Combine same year items to one object

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, json, ecmascript-6

I have an array of objects that look like this:

```
[
  {
    makeYear: 2019,
    company: 'Mazda',
    fleet: '900'
  },
  {
    makeYear: 2019,
    company: 'Mercedes',
    fleet: '500'
  },
  {
    makeYear: 2020,
    company: 'Honda',
    fleet: '390'
  },
  .....
]
```

I am trying to merge all the properties for a specific makeYear into one object that should look like this

```
[
  {
    makeYear: 2019,
    Mazda: 900,
    Mercedes: 500,
    //other companies present for the year
  },
  {
    makeYear: 2020,
    Honda: 390,
    //other companies present for the year
  },
  
];
```

I have tried it doing this way, but no luck.

```
const mergeObjs = input.reduce((res, item) => {
  if (!item.makeYear) return res;
  res[item.makeYear] = item;
  return res;
}, {});

const merged = input.filter(item => item.makeYear).map(item => {
  return {...item, ...(mergeObjs[item.makeYear] || {})}
});
```

Any idea how I can achieve this? TIA

Comment: Better result might be: `{ 2019: { Mazda: 900, Mercedes: 500 }, 2020: { Honda: 390 } }`

Comment: I would prefer having the key makeYear since that would be used for the frontend

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `reduce` to group with `makeYear` as a key.

```js
const data = [
    {
      makeYear: 2019,
      company: 'Mazda',
      fleet: '900'
    },
    {
      makeYear: 2019,
      company: 'Mercedes',
      fleet: '500'
    },
    {
      makeYear: 2020,
      company: 'Honda',
      fleet: '390'
    },
  ]
  
  
  const group = (makeYear, company, fleet) => {
    return data.reduce((acc, obj) => {
    let item = acc.find(i => i[makeYear] === obj[makeYear]);
    if (item) {
      item[company] = obj[fleet];
    } else {
      acc.push({
        [makeYear]: obj[makeYear],
        [obj[company]]: obj[fleet],
      })
    }
      return acc
    }, [])
  }
  
  console.log(group('makeYear', 'company', 'fleet'))
```

Comment: @boomchickawawa, updated, please check again.

Comment: this code would only run if the names of the keys match with the params in the reduce method. Is there a way to make it reusable for other objects to use this method as well?

Comment: the other objects would have only three key value pairs but their names would be changing

Comment: @boomchickawawa, can you edit your question and add examples of the objects, that this method doesn't work with?

Comment: for eg if the object has the same length but the names of the keys change, this method does not work as it specifically looks for makeYear, company and fleet

Comment: I just edit my answer, so you can specify the `keys` name from the `function` parameters.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `reduce()` to collect values for each year. Then use `entries()` and `map()` to get your desired structure.

This implementation uses a `Map`, but you can also use a plain JavaScript object.

```js
const input = [
  {
    makeYear: 2019,
    company: "Mazda",
    fleet: "900",
  },
  {
    makeYear: 2019,
    company: "Mercedes",
    fleet: "500",
  },
  {
    makeYear: 2020,
    company: "Honda",
    fleet: "390",
  },
];

const carsByYearAndMake = input.reduce((carsByYear, carsByMake) => {
  if (carsByYear.has(carsByMake.makeYear)) {
    const carsForYear = carsByYear.get(carsByMake.makeYear);
    carsForYear[carsByMake.company] = carsByMake.fleet;
  } else {
    carsByYear.set(carsByMake.makeYear, {
      [carsByMake.company]: carsByMake.fleet,
    });
  }
  return carsByYear;
}, new Map());

const output = [...carsByYearAndMake.entries()].map(
  ([year, fleetCountByMake]) => ({ year: year, ...fleetCountByMake })
);
console.log(JSON.stringify(output, null, 4));
```

```css
/* StackOverflow snippet: console should overlap rendered HTML area */
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, this works too, but @Mina answered first, so accepting their answer. Upvoting this anyway